# Boolean check if a rails engine is mounted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I have split one of my larger projects up into mountable rails engines and I want to find a method that checks if a rails engine is mounted.
As an example I have a User class in my main app

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :searches, as: :searchable, class_name: MySearchEngine::Search
end
```

I would like to wrap this has_many association as well as other code for the integration of the engine in an if statement so that it only adds the code if MySearchEngine has been mounted

Comment: how often are you mounting/unmounting the engine that you need to check if it's mounted? Or are you more just trying to keep the code in nice little distinct blocks in your model, in which case you could wrap up all the associations for user in, say a `MySearchEngine::UserConcerns` module or whatnot and include that. You could also take a look at [Custom configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#custom-configuration) and set config values for your app to include/not include things

Comment: Only the one time, but as soon as I looked at all the places where I made reference to the engine that would need to be commented out if the engine were unmounted I started looking into this. How could I use config values in the example case?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to check whether they are available by `defined? MySearchEngine::Search`

Comment: I had trouble using this in views using erb. If I wrap a link tag with a path defined in the engine in an if block using this method the link tag inside the block still gets evaluated and gives an error undefined local variable or method 'my_search_engine'. Ideally that tag would not be evaluated at all because it is inside the if block. so maybe a different method is needed for views. I think this was working however in my controllers and models.